# Phalcon initialize function in models

Tags: php, orm, initialization, phalcon

I have 3 models, Where

```
Basemodel
Model_A
Model_B

In Basemodel i have initialize function setting a property value

In Model_A i don't have initialize function, if i return anything from model 
it will be successful

In Model_B i have initialize function, if i return anything from this model 
its not returning anything. No Error, Nothing, Just Blank.
```

**Base Models With initialize()**

```
class Basemodel extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {

    protected $name;

    function initialize() {
        $this->name = 'MyApplication';
    }

}
```

**Model A Without initialize():**

```
class Model_a extends Basemodel {
    function test() {
        return $this->name; // WORKING
    }
}
```

**Model B With initialize():**

```
class Model_b extends Basemodel {
    public $b;
    function initialize() {
        $this->b = 'someName';
    }

    function rawtext() {
        return $this->name;  // NOT WORKING
    }
}
```

If remove **initialize()** from Model_B, Then its returning the value successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because in child classes you are overriding `BaseModel` `initialize` method.

If you want to extend `initilize` in child class you should call initialize from [parent](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) class - here `BaseModel`.

Model A/B should be:

```php
class Model_b extends Basemodel {
    public $b;
    function initialize() {
        parent::initialize(); // Call parent's class initialize
        $this->b = 'someName';
    }

    function rawtext() {
        return $this->name;  // SHOULD WORK
    }
}
```